# Bulk upload using csv file to remote MonetDB server

Tags: r, monetdb

I have a remote MonetDB server running and I want to bulk upload a csv file as it is much faster.

Based on the params in MonetDB.R, there is a csvdump=TRUE option but I don't think it works when you are trying to do this against a remote server. The server has to be local.

https://rdrr.io/github/MonetDB/monetdb-r/man/dbWriteTable.html

First, am I correct that I can't do this and if not, is there a workaround? I have a dataframe with +5M rows so it takes a long time with insert statements rather than using COPY INTO.

When I try using csvdump=TRUE against the remote server, it can't find the csv file because it is local to computer that called the dbWriteTable command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are right. As a workaround either use explicit `COPY INTO ON CLIENT` SQL statements or first use some file transfer tool to copy the file to the remote server before calling `dbWriteTable`.

It reads from MonetDB's documentation on [COPY INTO](https://www.monetdb.org/documentation-Sep2022/user-guide/sql-manual/data-loading/copy-from/):

> FROM files ON SERVER
>
> With ON SERVER, which is the default, the file name must be an
> absolute path on the system on which the database server (mserver5) is
> running. ...

Interestingly enough pymonetdb, the Python driver for MonetDB, uses ON CLIENT for bulk loads. From the [pymonetdb's doc](https://pymonetdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#file-uploads-and-downloads):

> File Uploads and Downloads
>
> Classes related to file transfer requests as used by COPY INTO ON
> CLIENT.

You might want to file an issue for the MonetDB R-driver project to have similar behavior as pymonetdb.